# How to design a mobile-based application for examination assessment

Tags: php, mobile

I want to design a mobile-based application that enable lectures set question through iphone.
I have had an website designed by PHP that lecture can set question through internet.
How to change and start?
Please tell me the detailed process. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question, because I don't understand what the problem is. How are people currently accessing your application from the computer? Via the web browser? Why can't they load that page in a mobile web browser? Or do you want to create an actual native application for a mobile device? If so, what device?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to design a mobile WEB application PHP should not be your first concern.

You will first need to understand the differences of styling web apps using CSS for mobile phones. There are some frameworks out there that can help you with this - I have never used one myself but a quick Google found http://www.phonegap.com/.

If you want to build actual native apps you will need to build them in that phones native language - iPhone is Objective-C, Android is a version of Java and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading this:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/mobile/a/write-web-pages-for-the-iphone.htm

and then go directly to [specifications](http://www.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is also one of the more popular frameworks to build mobile apps with HTML5/Javascript. Of course you can use any server side scripting language like PHP with it.

Comment: so if i have the PHP code for the website. How can i use it in this mobile-based application? I haven't contact this field ever, so i did't know at all.

Comment: See my comment on your question, do you want to build mobile web or a native app? We need to know what your actual problem is :)

Comment: it should be native application~

Comment: Then it all depends on how your current application is built. Is the backend nicely decoupled from the frontend stuff? If it is, you just build a native app that communicates with the backend the same way your web app already does. If it isn't, you probably have some work to do on your backend stuff :)

Comment: i didn't bulit any application current...in fact i really don't know how to start...i didn't understand mobile-based at all...

Comment: You already have a desktop web application. Why does the mobile one have to be native?

Comment: Because that web application is designed by my friend in PHP. I also don't know if that application has connected with internet or not. He only told me he can give me the code

Comment: Eh, ok. You need to know more before you even try to figure out what the issues will be. But either way, you will most likely need to know PHP and Objective-C and/or Java if doing the native version, OR PHP and HTML, CSS and JavaScript if doing a mobile web version.

Answer (score 0):

Building native apps for mobile devices is much different than building a web-based application for use by a larger (compatible) audience. If you desire the look and feel of a native app for your project, then you might think about building and app for the most popular of mobile device operating systems, such as for the iPhone, Blackberry, Android and any other mobile devices you want to include. Think of the native app for the mobile device as the customer service counter at your local department store, its a friendly and welcoming interface put in place to get you to the information you seek, quickly and efficiently. That's pretty much what your native application would be doing, if constructed with portability in mind. Which means you build a customer service counter for all different devices, while the PHP web-based application would become the tie in for all these devices onto one main source of information, your web server.

There are many ways to build both web-apps and mobile-apps, and even more ways to make them all interoperable. How you build the entire system from the floor up will definitely have an impact on the scalability, administration and interoperability and overall usability of your application.

Regardless of the avenue you plan to take in the development of your application, the core question must be answered. What purpose does this application serve or what need does it meet? By answering this simple question, your answer will present itself, as to what tools to use in the development of your application.